# how to get text from a div in an iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page that uses an iframe to do an ajax style file upload.  When the upload completes I'm writing a div to the iframe with the status of whether their file was uploaded or not.  The iframe is not visible and I'm using as a target for the form.  It all works fine except that I can't figure out how to use jquery to get the text within the div.  My iframe has an id of upload_target and the div in the iframe has the id of uploadStatus.  I thought the following would work but it doesn't.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks.

```
$("#upload_target").load(function () {
    alert($("#upload_target>  #uploadStatus").text());
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `iframe` has its `name` attribute set to `upload_target` as well, and then use

```
alert($("#uploadStatus", frames['upload_target'].document).text());
```

Comment: Add to this that your iframe has to have the same origin domain as the parent window for this to work.  Reading content served up by another domain would be considered a security violation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
$("#upload_target").load(function () {
    alert($("#uploadStatus").html());
 });
```

Once your iframe is loaded. Your div text will be alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ***Div*** as follows in one ***Iframe***

```
 <iframe id="ifrmReportViewer" name="ifrmReportViewer" frameborder="0" width="980"

     <div id="EndLetterSequenceNoToShow" runat="server"> 11441551 </div> Or

     <form id="form1" runat="server">        
       <div style="clear: both; width: 998px; margin: 0 auto;" id="divInnerForm">          

            Some Text

        </div>
     </form>
 </iframe>
```

Then you can find the text of those ***Div*** using the following code

```
var iContentBody = $("#ifrmReportViewer").contents().find("body");
var endLetterSequenceNo = iContentBody.find("#EndLetterSequenceNoToShow").text();

var divInnerFormText = iContentBody.find("#divInnerForm").text();
```

I hope this will help someone.