# jquery - how to get text of a div inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe, jquery-1.9

This `jsp` is inside the `iframe` which is generated dynamically ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> -->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/chat.css">
<title>Heart JSP page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="messageArea" class="divBorder">
    <% String intxnId = request.getParameter("intxnId");  %>
     Chat Interaction id is : ?<%= intxnId%> 

    </div>
    <div id="enterMessage" class="divBorder">
    Your message Area
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `iframe` and its `id` is generated dynamically.Inside the Iframe I inserted the above jsp page .

Now I need to get the text value of the div with `id=messageArea` in the jsp using jquery.

I used ,

```
    var  intxnId = `ch54p3443`;

var sss = $("#ch"+intxnId).contents().find("#messageArea").text();
alert("sss : "+sss);
```

`$("#ch"+intxnId)` will be my  iframe selector.

But no value is assigned to the variable `sss`.

Comment: is this iframe on the same domain? does your javascript console throw a warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326152/how-to-get-text-from-a-div-in-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: @Alex It doesnot throw any error.

Comment: and it is not cross-domain either? (I mean the content in the iframe is from the same domain as the main page)

Comment: @Balint can you please provide the solution code ?

Comment: What do you mean? Cross-domain iframe access is not working that easily, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the DOM object of the page inside your iframe first. And your iframe page must be from the same domain of the parent page due to the cross domain restriction.

I've set up a fiddle to show how to access the elements of a iframe page:

http://jsfiddle.net/ts5Z7/

Basically with your code, that means something like:

```
var  intxnId = `ch54p3443`;
var frameRef = $("#ch"+intxnId)[0];
var frameDocument = frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document :frameRef.contentDocument;

var sss = $(frameDocument).find("#messageArea").text();
alert("sss : "+sss);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But Not helped !

Comment: Is there anything else you need ? why not helping. I would like to help.